# Can I ask a class what type it needs for a generic?

Tags: java, generics, completable-future

I have a CompletableFuture whose type depends on the result returned from a message:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> getFuture(
    CompletableMessage message)
{
    ..
}
```

Example of some messages:

```
public class SomeMessageA implements CompletableMessage {
    .. // Future is UUID
}

public class SomeMessageB implements CompletableMessage {
    .. // Future is String
}

public class SomeMessageC implements CompletableMessage {
    .. // Future is Integer
}
```

I can already explicitly specify the generic:

```
CompletableFuture<UUID> a = getFuture(new SomeMessageA());
CompletableFuture<String> b = getFuture(new SomeMessageB());
CompletableFuture<Integer> c = getFuture(new SomeMessageC());
```

The trouble with this is that I won't find if a mistake has been made until runtime.

Is there a way I can acquire the generic type for the future by asking the message for the class of object is being returned?

I can do this in C++ like this:

```
class SomeMessageA {
public:
    typedef int future_t;
};

SomeMessageA::future_t a;
```

Can I do something similar in Java or will I always have to reference the documentation for expected type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make `CompletableMessage` generic too, specifying its return type:

```
public interface CompletableMessage<T> {
...
```

And then inherit specific message with the type:

```
public class SomeMessageA implements CompletableMessage<Uuid> {
...
```

And match the types for `getFuture()` method:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> getFuture(CompletableMessage<T> message) {
...
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.